# Form returning nil values instead of form values and so insert and commit doesn't show on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie and has just started learning rails, so please ignore the silly bugs

GodsController

```
class GodsController< ApplicationController
    def index
        @g=God.all
    end
    def new
        @g=God.new()
    end
    def create
        @g=God.new(g_params)
        if @g.save
            redirect_to @g
        else
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end
    def g_params
        params.fetch(:g,{}).permit(:name , :ph_no , :bhakts)

    end
end
```

schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_04_18_112327) do
  create_table "gods", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "ph_no"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "bhakts"
  end

end
```

model God

```
class God < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Form for inserting new values

```
<h1> Insert new God </h1>

<%= form_with model: @g do |form| %>
<div>
<%= form.label :name %>
<%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div>
<%= form.label :ph_no %>
<%= form.text_field :ph_no %>
</div>
<div>
<%= form.label :bhakts %>
<%= form.text_field :bhakts %>
</div>
<div>
<%= form.submit%>
</div>
<%end %>
```

Html page for showing the list of gods

```
<h1> <b> MY GODS !! </b></h1>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Name</th>
<th> ph_no</th>
<th> Bhakts</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <% @g.each do |x| %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= x.name%></td>
 <td><%= x.ph_no%></td>
<td><%= x.bhakts%></td>
</tr>
<% end%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to insert values name:ram ph_no: 4487878886 and bhakts:23
but the terminal is showing error as following message is displayed

```
Started POST "/gods" for ::1 at 2023-04-20 12:29:09 +0530
Processing by GodsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "god"=>{"name"=>"Divya Pratap Singh", "ph_no"=>"76678", "bhakts"=>"45"}, "commit"=>"Create God"}
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/gods_controller.rb:10:in `create'
  God Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "gods" ("name", "ph_no", "created_at", "updated_at", "bhakts") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", nil], ["ph_no", nil], ["created_at", "2023-04-20 06:59:09.914114"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-20 06:59:09.914114"], ["bhakts", nil]]
  ↳ app/controllers/gods_controller.rb:10:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/gods_controller.rb:10:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/gods/15
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 2305)


Started GET "/gods/15" for ::1 at 2023-04-20 12:29:09 +0530
  
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for GodsController):
  
 `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/gods/new" for ::1 at 2023-04-20 12:29:10 +0530
Processing by GodsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering gods/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered gods/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1174)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 3313)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3585)
```

Comment: Well, my bad. You can add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

well , I figured out there are two errors which i had to take care of

Firstly i am trying to access the instance object @g in params[:g][:name] or ph_no or bhakts in my gods_controller create action therefore it is showing nill values and commiting with  nill values in my db
( I checked it out with

> puts @g.inspect

)

The correction here is that the params hash is accessible to the god model so the g_params func should be like

> params.fetch(:god,{}).permit(:name , :ph_no , :bhakts)

instead of

> params.fetch(:g,{}).permit(:name , :ph_no , :bhakts)

ps : i could have written

> params.require(:god).permit(:name , :ph_no , :bhakts)

secondly redirect_to @g is wrong as yet i have not defined show action for my resource

> redirect_to @g